# Assignee True to a variable if the environment variable is defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to check if env variable is defined in Python. From previous threads I learn that I can use:

```
if os.environ.get('abc')=='True':
    # defined
```

But I would like to set a global variable and assigned True if the env exists, otherwise False. I tried:

```
X = os.environ.get('abc')
```

But if it is not defined than `X` is None and if it's defined it is the env's assigned value.
How can I achieve the wanted result?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign it this Boolean expression:

```
X = os.environ.get('abc') is not None
```

which is `True` if `os.environ.get('abc')` is defined, and `False` if it is `None` (undefined).

Answer (score 0):

Get allows for specifing a default value:

`X = os.environ.get('abc', False)`

Comment: `X` should be True or False only

Answer (score 0):

Assignee True to a variable if the environment variable is defined:

```
abc = os.environ.get('abc')
X = abc is not None
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.

Comment: @HarshaBiyani better?

Answer (score 0):

`get` isn't the only thing you can do with `os.environ`. Like any good mapping, `os.environ` supports `in` for testing whether a key is present:

```
X = 'abc' in os.environ
```